# Create/Edit middle model class in many-to-many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently, my app have 3 models,
I want to add new Receipt by specifying the quantity of food required.

```
class Receipt < ActiveRecord::Base
  # columns: id, place
  has_many :receipt_foods
  has_many :foods, through: :receipt_food
end

class ReceiptFood < ActiveRecord::Base
  # columns: id, quantity, receipt_id, food_id
  belongs_to :receipt
  belongs_to :food
end

class Food < ActiveRecord::Base
  # columns: id, name
  has_many :receipt_foods
  has_many :receipts, through: :receipt_food
end
```

My problem is how to create the quantity of food in my form,
for example: create 3 different food where 3 quantity each food

I know how to create this in `rails console` only, don't know how in web using `form_for`
I have try `fields_for` but most examples explain create and edit 2 models property only.
Can any one suggest ways or any materials/articles talk about this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I would do:

```
= form_for :receipt_food do |f|
  = f.number_field :quantity, min: 0
  = f.select :food_id, Food.all.map{ |food| [food.name, food.id] }
  = f.select :receipt_id, Receipt.all.map{ |receipt| [receipt.place, receipt.id] }
```

I would add labels to these fields.

Also, I think the convention is to name it: `FoodReceipt`, it's alphabetical.

Comment: how about i want to add newe food and receipt from receipt_food ?